# WPF: Labels that data binded are hard to work with when manipulating in visual studio.

Tags: .net, wpf

Say I have the following XAML for a WPF User Control:

```
<Grid Background="#FFCBCBCB">
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"  Margin="115,10,10,91"/>
<Grid/>
```

When the program runs the view gets a object bounded to it with a property called Name. However the label contains no text when working on it in Visual studio.

**Is there a way to have a development only place holder so that i can better visualize what the control will look like?**

I have read about fallbackvalue, however that seems to only work with strings that don't have spaces.

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Name, FallbackValue=Iamonelongstring}"  Margin="115,10,10,91"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your looking for is `DesignData`

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/08/27/designdata-mvvm-support-in-blend-vs2010-and-wpf-silverlight.aspx

Should give a good intro

You can basically setup a design time view model to give data at design time alone

http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX11/OPN03

In the above video you can also see the presenter create and use Design time data

On a side-note, `FallbackValue` can support spaces, wrap your text in single quotes.

Something like:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Name, FallbackValue='I am one long string'}"  Margin="115,10,10,91"/>
```

You do not want to be doing this though, since `FallbackValue` isn't just for Design time but it's intended for a totally different purpose. You should look into `DesignData` and put it to use to help with your design time working(It offers quite a bit more help when you say have things like Collections and binding with DataContexts as objects in that group. FallbackValue will then become useless even if chosen to be used)